# Can't click a button into loritta's website with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, button, xpath

Soo basically i was trying to make a python program to get my daily rewards from a discord bot, but i can't manage to click into the button " Pegar Premio".

My code: (I'm new to python)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=PathToMyProfile")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://loritta.website/br/daily")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name^='a-'][src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']"))).click()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="daily-wrapper"]/div[3]/div').click()

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andersonbap, seems the element you want to click "Pegar Premio" button is not inside the iframe so I removed that line. Also I changed the selector for the button. The following is working for me. time.sleep() are added so you can see what is happening on the page which you can remove once things are working:

```
driver.get("https://loritta.website/br/daily")
time.sleep(5)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "button-discord"))).click()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="daily-wrapper"]/div[3]/div').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thx ketanvj, you helped me a lot, i learned about the class_name thing and discovered what was the problem itself.
The problem wasn't with clicking the button itself, the problem was that the button (idk how) just became unavailable to selenium when i do the captcha with it.
(When you login with your discord account, theres a captcha you need to do before you can get the daily reward)

Comment: Glad that it helped you. You can accept the answer if it has worked for you. Thanks.